# Connect Raspberry Pi to Android device via bluetooth

Tags: java, android, python, bluetooth, raspberry-pi3

I just started of using raspberry Pi 3(Model B). I want to establish a bluetooth connection between raspberry pi and android device. Manually I am able to do a connection with android device but I want to run a program(python or any other language) so when I run it search the nearby device and connect with some specific device. How I achieve this? If any one have program similar like this then it is very helpful for me. I want to do code on Raspberry Pi which connect with diffrent device and collect the data.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

Comment: Hi Mihit, I made a bluetooth library for Android and it is very simple to manage all these stuff you're talking about. You may want to give it a shot! https://github.com/omaflak/Bluetooth-Library

Comment: Hi A. Omar, I want to write and run a program from raspberry Pi not from an android app. Raspberry Pi is searching for a nearby device and connect with one specific device.